# Unale to run bundle install in iOS App directory

Tags: ios, rubygems, fastlane

So my project can be found at https://github.com/WhiteWhiskyWolf/all_you

I'm trying to get fastlane working to build my KMM app for iOS and Android. However, when I run `bundle install` in the `iosApp` directory, I get the following error.

```
In Gemfile:
  cocoapods was resolved to 1.10.2, which depends on
    cocoapods-core was resolved to 1.10.2, which depends on
      algoliasearch was resolved to 1.27.5, which depends on
        json


Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/caseydaniel/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/unf_ext-0.0.8.2/ext/unf_ext
/Users/caseydaniel/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for -lstdc++... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

I've installed command line tools a few times now, and tried the GCC compiler. rbenv install fails for a similar reason. I've tried both command line tools for xcode 14.2 and 14.3 beta

Answer (score 0):

reinstall of xcode seemed to fix the problem.